# Validation of Express request based on Swagger YAML

Tags: node.js, express, yaml, swagger

Is out there a node module for validation of the schema/values provided in Express req object, based on Swagger YAML schema definition for that request?

Let's say this is relevant part of the YAML:

```
  /books/{genre}:
    get:
    parameters:
      - name: genre
        in: path
        required: true
        type: string
      - name: size
        in: query
        required: false
        type: number
```

A req object derived from the following request should pass validation:

```
GET /books/sci-fi          
GET /books/thriller?size=5
```

And this one should fail:

```
GET /books/12
```

Comment: You can actually google "nodejs swagger" or hit up npm with a similar search and find a pretty great tool for building express based swagger apps.

Comment: @Paul I've tried it of course. I wanted to base my server on Swagger, but I couldn't figure out how to customize my routers, error handling... Do you have a concrete library that matches my question?

Comment: Yes, but that's actually off topic for the site, which is why you're getting Close votes.  Stack is about asking folks to help you solve problems in code you've written, not to help you google and evaluate tools.

Comment: You could fix it by picking the top rated swagger library (e.g. Node-swagger), following the tutorial and hen posting here the question in the form, "here is what I have tried.  It doesn't do X that I need, how can I make it do X?"

Comment: Thank you Paul. Is there a site to help me evaluate tools?

Answer (score 1):

To generate a template node.js server using a yaml file, try swagger.io > Swagger Editor > Online Editor > build your yaml in the left pane > Generate Server > Node.js

The downloadable package will use swagger-tools for validation. The default index.js in the generated code will define that your controllers (custom code to handle each request) will live in the controllers directory:

```
// swaggerRouter configuration
var options = {
  swaggerUi: '/swagger.json',
  controllers: './controllers',
  useStubs: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? true : false // Conditionally turn on stubs (mock mode)
};
```

Add these elements to the endpoint definition to define the controller name and the method name:

You can add this property to your endpoint definition to tell the swagger-tools middleware which javascript file will handle the request:

```
x-swagger-router-controller: myController
operationId: myMethod
```

Create a controllers directory containing myController.js that exports myMethod:

```
module.exports.myMethod = myMethod;
function myMethod(req, res) {
  //do stuff
  res.end();
}
```

The inputs will be validated before the request is routed to your controller.

Comment: quick question regarding this, I've successfully set all the above up ^. Swagger is currently offering me server-side validation (which is good), however if I was to use this app in production would I need to use another form of server-side validation and not use Swagger?

Comment: I use middleware.swaggerValidator() to validate incoming payload. In prod. I do have a custom error handler to intercept the swagger-default error messages and transform it into what I want.  Details here: https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools/issues/366